# Dockerfile - cache packages for faster rebuild?

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which build a RESTApi. Whenever I change a line of code in my code and want to rebuild the container, everything gets installed from 0 (code is in the app folder). This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use the Python3.7.2 image
FROM python:3.7.2-stretch

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app 
ADD . /app

# grab the key that LLVM use to GPG-sign binary distributions
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt -y install clang


# Install Mono (careful: Docker image runs on Debian 9)
RUN apt -y install apt-transport-https dirmngr gnupg ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
RUN echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install mono-complete

## Install python libraries
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mono /app/pythonnet/tools/nuget/nuget.exe update -self

RUN git config --global http.proxy http://my.proxy.address:port
RUN /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -U pycparser --user
RUN /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -U pythonnet --user

# run the command to start uWSGI
CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```

Building this image takes a very long time, and since I only change a few lines of code, a complete rebuild is an undesired behaviour.

I run `docker build -t flask_app .` to build the image. Is there anyway to only reinstall certain packages doing changes only in my codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker build` uses a [layer cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) that can avoid rebuilding parts of the image.  The basic rule here is that, as soon as you `COPY` (or `ADD`) a file that's changed, everything after that line in the Dockerfile will always be repeated.  Things before a `COPY` directive, or if Docker can tell the file that's being `COPY`ed hasn't changed, will get skipped over (the layer from the previous build is reused).

To support this a typical Dockerfile is laid out like:

```
FROM some-base-image
RUN commands to install OS-level dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY only files that declare language-level dependencies ./
RUN commands to install language-level dependencies
COPY . ./
RUN commands to build the application
CMD the single command to launch the application
```

Note the two separate `COPY` commands.  The OS-level dependencies are reused, if the text of the `RUN` command(s) hasn't changed; the language-level dependencies are reused if their specific file hasn't changed; and the application itself is usually always rebuilt.

In the context of your Dockerfile, you should make all of the `RUN apt-get ...` commands run *before* you `COPY` anything.  (It's good practice to have only a single `apt-get install`; it's important to have it be in the same `RUN` command as an `apt-get update`.)  Then copy *only* the `requirements.txt` file and `RUN pip install`; and then copy the rest of the application.

```
FROM python:3.7.2-stretch
# Rearrange this so there is only one apt-get install line
# (Do you need all of these dependencies?)
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      apt-transport-https \
      apt-utils \
      ca-certificates \
      clang \
      curl \
      dirmngr \
      gnupg \
      software-properties-common
# Similarly install Mono (is it actually needed?)

# Copy and install just Python dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
# There are no requirements that aren't in the requirements.txt file
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the app in
COPY . .

# Standard runtime metadata
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```